# Prolog defining a male

Tags: prolog, rules

So my lecturer wrote this code as an answer to one of a question. Today we found out that the rule male and female are both wrong, can somebody confirm this for me? Also, taking advantage of of this post I would like to ask you kind people if you could send/link me a tutorial explaining prolog in detail, if you could do this it'd be great! Thanks a lot.

```
/* FACTS */

parents(david, george, noreen).
parents(jennifer, george, noreen).
parents(georgejr, george, noreen).
parents(scott, george, noreen).
parents(joanne, george, noreen).
parents(jessica, david, edel).
parents(clara, david, edel).
parents(michael, david, edel).
parents(laura, georgejr, susan).
parents(anna, scott, siobhan).
parents(edel, mick, peggy).
parents(maria, mick, peggy).
parents(assumpta, mick, peggy).
parents(patrick, kevin, maria).
parents(hugh, kevin, maria).
parents(helena, kevin, maria).
parents(roisin, wim, assumpta).


/* Relationships */

father(X, Y) :- parents(Y, X, _).
male(X) :- father(X, _).

mother(X, Y) :- parents(Y, _, X).
female(X) :- mother(X, _).

grandfather(X, Y) :- father(X, Z), father(Z, Y).
grandfather(X, Y) :- father(X, Z), mother(Z, Y).

grandmother(X, Y) :- mother(X, Z), mother(Z, Y).
grandmother(X, Y) :- mother(X, Z), father(Z, Y).

brother(X, Y) :- male(X), father(Z, X), father(Z, Y), X \== Y.

sister(X, Y) :- female(X), father(Z, X), father(Z, Y), X \== Y.

/* New realtionships */

parent(X,Y) :- father(X,Y); mother(X,Y).

uncle(X,Y) :- parent(Z,Y), brother(X,Z), Z \== X.

aunt(X,Y) :- parent(Z,Y), sister(X,Z), Z \== X.

sibling(X,Y) :-  brother(X,Y); sister(X,Y).

cousin(X,Y) :- parent(Z,X), parent(W,Y), sibling(Z,W).
```

Comment: the db doesn't allow to state the sex of a child...

Comment: So the only way to be male or female is to be a mother or a father. Until then you have no sex at all in this dataset. For example, jennifer and michael both are sexless. Unless you have "I'm my own grandpa" family trees, someone will be left that way.

Comment: `male(X)` only works for fathers and assumes the father is the second argument always in `parents/3`. `female(X)` only works for mothers, and assumes the mother is the third argument always in `parents/3`. `male` and `female` won't work on the kids (because of what @CappelliC says). For tutorial, could try http://www.learnprolognow.org/.

Comment: `male/1` and `female/1` are not "wrong", they are - at best - incomplete.

Comment: Right. If any of you can complete it for me. I'd be sooo thankful! Cheers!

Comment: In words, how do you want `male` and `female` defined? If it's to cover every person in your database, then I think CapelliC gave you the right clue. Take a stab at it...

Comment: Right I figured that male and female was just not meant for the children.